# how to rank values in column A in column B with id?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013, microsoft-excel-2016

how to rank values in column A in column B with ID with formula as shown in the picture ?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Excel [`RANK`](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/rank-function-6a2fc49d-1831-4a03-9d8c-c279cf99f723) function for exactly this purpose:

For your example, enter the following formula in cell `C3`, and drag it down to fill the cells beneath:

```
=RANK(B3,$B$3:$B$11,1)
```

This formula states:

*What is the rank of the value held by cell `B3` when all values in the range `$B$3:$B$11` are sorted in Ascending order? (ascending since the final argument is `1`)*

Note however, that this will yield duplicate `ID` values if duplicates are present in your `Values` column - this could be problematic if you are using this to construct some form of database.